# Delete relationship between two tables in Hibernate (HQL)

Tags: java, hibernate, servlets, hql

I have two tables (Resources & Tags) and the third that connects both of them(Resources_tags). How can I delete the many-to-many relationship of a resource with several tags with a HQL query?
For example, I want to delete all the tags that a resource have in Resources_tags table.

Answer (score 0):

If your two tables are "A" and "B" then
when you set up your two tables you need to specify "cascade" on table "A".

like this:

```
<bag name="A"
  inverse="true"
  lazy="false"
  cascade="all">
  <key column="SOME_ID"/>
  .....
```

Now any deletes performed on "A" should have the desired effect.

Comment: Can you give me a HQL query example please?

Comment: What I meant by "any deletes on 'A'" is that it doesn't need to be HQL.  That is up to you and driven by your application.  Usually, the idea in Hibernate is to work with objects, so there are a variety of ways to delete.  You can just say:  sess.delete(myObjOfTypeA);

Comment: Sorry, hit enter there too fast my mistake!   Normally, for the relation type you describe you should get a list of the objects, modify it (say by removing items) and save the list.  However, you can still delete via HQL as well:
 
Query deleteExample = session.createQuery(
    "delete item from Items where itemType = ?");

Comment: Here's is what I'm trying to do: Resources res = (Resources)session.load(Resources.class, 1);
Set tagses = res.getTagses(); Am I doing right? Now how can I remove all the references?

Comment: Just say: sess.delete(res)  [Note: you _will_ need to flush the session to commit the transaction with the deletes...]